# How to execute ffmpeg commands synchronously?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, async-await

I have a video processing API and I want to run ffmpeg commands synchronously otherwise processed files are getting corrupted.

So far I tried the steps below:

```
var execute = (command) => {
  const ffmpeg = spawn("./bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg", command);
  ffmpeg.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    debug(data.toString());
  });

  ffmpeg.on("close", () => {
    console.log('DONE');
  });
};

var sourceFilePath = '/tmp/test.mp4';
var outputPath = '/tmp/test_processed.mp4';
var ss = 5;
var t = 10;

execute([
  "-i",
  sourceFilePath,
  "-ss",
  ss,
  "-t",
  t,
  outputPath,
]);

await uploadTos3(outputPath); // Helper function to upload processed file to s3
```

The uploaded file is not working.. It's getting corrupted.

Note:
When I try to upload a working video it's working. So the problem is with the ffmpeg helper function.

Comment: The child_process methods have sync equivalents. For example: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options

Comment: Wow cool. So I'll use it like `child_process.spawnSync` right? @sdgluck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should convert your `execute` function to this:

```
exports.execute = async (command) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ffmpeg = spawn("./bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg", command);
    ffmpeg.once('error',reject);
    ffmpeg.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      debug(data.toString(); //I'm not sure what debug is
    });

    ffmpeg.on("exit", (code,signal) => {
      if(signal)
        code = signal;
      if(code != 0) {
        reject(new Error(`Returned exit code ${code}`);
        console.log('Error');
      }
      else {
        resolve(); // Call resolve here
        console.log('DONE');
      }
    });
  });
};
await execute([  // Call function with `await`
  "-i",
  sourceFilePath,
  "-ss",
  ss,
  "-t",
  t,
  outputPath,
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Murat. I've converted `spawn` to `spawnSync` thanks for sgdluk in the comments. It worked!